# Seem to have a voltage problem after reconnecting meter box - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I replaced the wire from the meter box up to the service connection because it was damaged last winter when a tree pulled the wire from the house - although the service man said it was still sound the outside casing was ripped in a few places and should be replace someday. (since we were having the house sided I thought that would be a good time to do it)
Had a disconnect put up a new wire. But now the light seem to flicker more when the water pump comes on and when we start the microwave after a few seconds it sounds like it drops in power. 
I tried not to tighten the lugs too much - said 50lb torque and did that - the clamps didn't look dirty but I also didn't clean them - where should I start. - will cost to have another disconnect.

Comment: Did you use copper or aluminum for the new wires?  Can you post a photo of the labeling on your meter box? (50 in-lbs sounds a bit small for meter H/N lugs)

Comment: aluminum - checking...
Damn - the tag was inside the meter box. I glanced at it and got my torque wrench, I remember it was not there when I got back - just checked now and found it on the ground 50lb for slotted head ,100lb FOR HEX - mine were hex.
Might be the problem
Time to get thoes glasses I have been putting off.

Answer (score 2):

I should have tightened them more -- looks like 100lb not 50lb

Comment: I'm glad you found the wayward label!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a loose connection, did you actually use a torque wench and follow the guidelines for the type of metal the wiring was made from and use anti-ox if it was aluminum?